# Unable to notify second device when receive image from blob

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I am working a chat application and when when I upload a image with button click then image doesn't received to another device only sender device showing it.

```
MyButton click code:
 public async void Image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                {
                    CompressionQuality = 50,
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
                });
                FileName = file.Path;
                FileName = FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                //IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(FileName);
                //var filee = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync(filename2);

                //Stream stream = await filee.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read);

                content.Add(new StreamContent(file.GetStream()),
                    "\"file\"",
                    $"\"{file.Path}\"");

                byteData = Model.Convert.ToByteArray(FileName);

                var im = ImageSource.FromStream(this.file.GetStream);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                    file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    file.Dispose();
                    // return memoryStream.ToArray();
                    uploadedFilename = await AzureStorage.UploadFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()));
                }


                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uploadedFilename))
                {
                    var imageData = await AzureStorage.GetFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, uploadedFilename);

                    var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageData));

                    TextContainer.Add(new MessageText { imgsource = img });
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;


                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
```

I am Also using ObservableCollection but unable to get image to second device:

```
 public ObservableCollection<MessageText> TextContainer { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MessageText>();
```

Upload fileCode which I have used to upload my file:

```
  public static async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(ContainerType containerType, Stream stream)
        {
            var container = GetContainer(containerType);
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var fileBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            await fileBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

            return name;
        }
```

Comment: Based on your code, I just see the processing for uploading a image to blob storage and saved into `TextContainer` on the sender device side. How did you send message(s) to another device? And how did your another device receive the message(s) sent from the sender device?

Comment: I have used SignalR, I have done it. Thanks for rply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used SignalR and its working fine for me